# Sigma notation using induction

Tags: proof-writing

Suppose that n∈N, $$\sum_{k=1}^n (2k+1) = n^2+2n$$

Base Case:n=1

⟹2∗1+1=3=12+2∗1

the base case holds true

I.H, Assume its true for $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} (2k+1) = n^2+2n$$

Then;

$$\implies\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} (2k+1) = n^2+2n$$

$$\implies\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} (2k+1) = (n+1)^2+2(n+1)$$ Im confused how to proceed next?

Comment: try splitting the sum in such a way that you can use the induction hypothesis you need to show that $$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} (2k+1) = (n+1)^2+2(n+1)$$

Comment: @asddf do i have to worry about the 2k+1?

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: $$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} (2k+1) $$=$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} (2k+1) +2(n+1)+1$$

Comment: @asddf can  u check my updated answer, is that what u wanted, splitting it?

Comment: I saw your edit, the thing is you dont know whether $$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} (2k+1) = (n+1)^2+2(n+1)$$ is true, you only know that the induction hypothesis is true, try using induction hypothesis on the 4th comment in the first sum which goes up to n and then $(n+1)^2 +2(n+1)$ should come out

Comment: @TheGamer How is this not a duplicate of your other question: [Proving $1+3+\cdots+(2n-1) = n^2$ using induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2331877/proving-13-cdots2n-1-n2-using-induction). Just because the index of summation is shifted by $1$ doesn't make it a different problem.

Comment: cuz idk how to do sigma notation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n (2k+1) $$

and let $n\ge 1$ be such that
$$S_n=n^2+2n .$$

we must prove that
$$S_{n+1}= (n+1)^2+2(n+1)$$

we have by definition
 $$S_{n+1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}(2k+1)$$
$$=S_n+2 (n+1)+1$$
$$=n^2+2n+2 (n+1 )+1$$
$$=n^2+2n+1+2(n+1 )$$
$$=(n+1)^2+2 (n+1) $$
Qed.